# what is Vec4i in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

i am learning opencv using c++. i came across Vector in a code for hough line transform . can anyone explain me what does Vec4i store and what does 4i mean.
the code snippet:-

```
vector<Vec4i> lines;
  HoughLinesP(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 50, 50, 10 );
  for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
  {
    Vec4i l = lines[i];
    line( cdst, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
  }
```

Comment: A Vec4i is a type holding 4 integers. Here is where it is defined: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#vec

Comment: Its a tuple of 4 integers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at the [OpenCV Basic Structures](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#vec).
Vec4i is a structure for representing a vector with 4 dimensions, with each value an `int`

If you look at the [HoughLinesP() documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghlinesp#houghlinesp) you'll see what each dimension in is in this particular case:

> lines – Output vector of lines. Each line is represented by a 4-element vector  (x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2) , where  (x_1,y_1) and  (x_2, y_2) are the ending points of each detected line segment.

In short, each line is a Vec4i, the first two elements are the line's start point (x1,y1) and last two are the line's end point(x2,y2)